# Want to run a cpp executable in a new terminal and then send a file into the input stream

Tags: c++, linux, istream, xterm

I would like to run a c++ executable in a new linux terminal, which I am doing using:

```
xterm -e executable options &disown
```

and this works. However, I also need to parse a text file through the command line. Normally, the file would be parsed by:

```
./executable options < inputFile.txt
```

and then the file is handled by the c++ code using this function:

```
void parse_lines(istream &in){
    verify_version_number(in);
    read_variables(in);
    ...
}
```

However the following line does not work:

```
xterm -e executable options < inputFile.txt &disown
```

**How can I run the executable in a new terminal and then send the contents of `inputFile.txt` into the istream?**

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you get? I suspect the problem is the ampersand. This is a special character in Linux to background a process.

Comment: @JamesShewey Hi, there is no error, the file just doesn't parse. Removing &disown doesn't fix it.

Comment: It looks like perhaps your inputFile.txt is being sent to xterm, not to your executable. You might need to try xterm -e bash -c "executable options < inputFile.txt" - unfortunately I don't have an xwindows install to play around with to check and see if you can just do xterm -e "executable options < inputFile.txt"

Comment: You could make a bash script contianing your executable command `#!/bin/sh` `executable options < inputFile.txt`, then launch `xterm -e myscript.sh` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put quotes around the command, it will be sent to the shell as a single command, and the special characters `<` and `&` will be interpreted in the shell running *within* xterm rather than in the shell where you *start* xterm:

```
xterm -e "executable options < inputFile.txt &disown"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `x-terminal-emulator` instead of `xterm`. Perhaps it works.